# How to define the boundary operator using the exterior derivative?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am looking for a way to define the boundary operator $\partial : M^n \to N^{n-1}$ from an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ to its boundary $N$ using the the expression

\begin{equation*}
\int_M d \alpha = \int_{\partial M} \alpha \ . 
\end{equation*}
I believe this can be done solely using the notion of currents and the support of $d \alpha$ without reference to Stokes' theorem (which relies on a definition of $\partial$), but cannot find a suitable (rigorous) reference anywhere that expands the Wikipedia entry (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_%28mathematics%29#Homological_theory).

I am particularly interested whether, on complex manifolds, the boundary operator can admit a Dolbeault decomposition as is claimed in the "Current" entry on Encyclopedia of Mathematics https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Current.

Comment: Why do you think it can be done without Stokes's Theorem? Also, do you know any cohomology?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_%28mathematics%29#Homological_theory. Yes I know some cohomology.

Comment: I followed the link. I still don't know why there must be a way to express the boundary that way. I just see a way to express the corresponding integral.

Comment: "...In view of this formula we can DEFINE a boundary operator on arbitrary currents... " Stokes' Theorem can then be viewed as a consequence of this definition for the action of the boundary operator on a homological space, rather than the other way around.

Comment: "On currents," not the spaces themselves. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by not the spaces themselves? Obviously a definition for the boundary operator on an arbitrary current defines the action of the boundary operator on the space of currents.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if it's obvious, why are you asking us this question?